Is it possible to grow a closed hashing/open addressing hash table in place?
I am writing my own specialized implementation of a hash table in C#. The purpose is to store string instances where the keys may also be ReadOnlySpan and ReadOnlySequence. I chose closed hashing/open addressing strategy with double hashing where XxHash3 is the initial index hash and FNV1a64 is the function for the probing step.
I have problem with implementing the in-place grow algorithm when the load factor is > 0.75 or if collisions are to large. For the most part my algorithm works as intended. The problem is when a string I need to rehash collides with another string even after resizing. I then calculate the step function and go to the next position. If the next position is already occupied it may be there from before the growth operation or it may have been put there during the growth operation. If it was there before I can switch the value I am currently rehashing with the one that still needs to be rehashed. Otherwise I go to the next position and repeat the process. The problem is that I don't know how would I determine if given position was put there before or during growth without storing additional data with the values or without extra memory to store it during growth.
If I simply allocate a new memory and iterate over the old one this problem isn't there since all values in the new memory must be also new. At this point I wonder if an in-place growth algorithm for such a hash table is even possible without additional storage.
If anyone knows or already made such a growth algorithm I am interested in how you solved the problem I described above. Otherwise I would appreciate if someone can explain to me why doing it in-place is not viable.
While I am programming in C# I guess the general topic is language agnostic.

I'm wondering how you expect to grow the underlying array "in place".  That would be required first, right?

Marshall.ReAllocHGlobal because I want it to be unmanaged memory. The memory contents are copied automatically.

@patvax: "ReAllocHGlobal / the memory contents are copied automatically" - if the memory contents need to be deep-copied every time anyway, you've lost what is for most people the main benefit of in-place rehashing.

@TonyDelroy Not every time. If the OS can find enough memory after the current buffer it will simply resize the memory lease. In that case no deep copy would be needed and true in-place growth would happen.


The problem is that I don't know how would I determine if given position was put there before or during growth without storing additional data with the values or without extra memory to store it during growth.

You don't actually need to know, as what actually matters is how appropriate the bucket position is given the new table size.
Let's refer to the two hash functions as h1(element) and h2(element), being the ideal-bucket-index hash and bucket-jump hash for whatever post-resize bucket count is...

as you iterate over the hash table, if bucket B is occupied by element E:

for attempt = 0; attempt <= max_attempts; ++attempt

evaluate viability of rehashing/moving E from bucket B to bucket
B' = h1(E) + attempt * h2(E) (%-ed into bucket count):

if that's the original bucket B, break attempts, keep iterating
if it's a tombstone or empty/unused, claim it, break attempts, keep iterating
if it's occupied by incumbent element "I":

for i_attempt = 0; i_attempt <= max_attempts; ++i_attempt

see if you can move I "backwards" by h2(I) (%-ed) to find a tombstone or empty element (if so move I & E, break, keep iterating buckets), or if you reach h1(I) and it's occupied:

if i_attempt > attempt

then let E take I's actual (not ideal) bucket, and advance by h2(I) to find a new home for I,
else advance by h2(E) to find a new home for E (handling further collisions as above for each incumbent element)















This won't give you optimal rehashing (removing all tombstones, getting elements as close as possible to their ideal bucket locations aka minimising collision chain lengths, and repeats work of trying to rehouse elements multiple times so can have horrible performance for really high load factor or collision-prone keys), but because you're only considering re-housing of two elements - E and I - at any one point in time, there's O(1) extra memory required (but more CPU / memory-access for redundant "repacking" checks).
Note: if you've picked h2 and bucket count so all buckets will be visited eventually, then max_attempts can be infinite - you'll never loop indefinitely anyway.

In the end I actually dropped the in-place idea and moved old items into a new empty buffer. This way I can simply reuse my insertion algorithm and drop the old buffer after all elements have been added to the new one. This forfeits one small optimization where ReAllocHGlobal was able to acquire memory immediately after my buffer so that no copy is needed. As soon as I get the time I will look at your answer in greater detail.
